# 403 - Forbidden on basic MVC 3 deploy on iis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, which runs on a IIS 7.5. Everything works great if i access the application locally from the Windows Server, but if i try to access it from a remote client the browser throws an error.

The HTML loads fine when i try to access the site remotely, but when it make AJAX calls it fails with this msg:

*POST 403 (Forbidden: header 'Content-Type' value denied)*

I have tried:
 - using jQuery jsonp
 - Granting webfolder accees to "Everyone" in Folder security and sharing

Do you have any other suggentions for a solution?

Comment: Generally when I've seen stuff like this, IIS is running your site under it's limited user instead of the application pool user.

Comment: how do i check this? The Application Pool is set to ASP.NET v4.0

Answer (score 5):

Check if the file global.asax exists.
I had get the same problem because I forgot to upload this file.

Answer (score 3):

Does your web server have ASP.NET 4 installed? You may need to run this command:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30128\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Edit: OK, so this wasn't the problem... Security is the next thing to check: This article might help you... http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: thanks again for your time, but i just can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I've seen stuff like this, IIS is running your site under it's limited user instead of the application pool user.

To check this configuration you need to access IIS Manager, expand the computer name, expand sites, expand the web site that contains your application, select your application in the tree view.

Under the IIS settings region, select Authentication (double click it, or click open feature)

Select Anonymous Authentication, click edit... from actions on the right. In the dialog that opens check the setting for Anonymous user identity: it should be set to application pool identity.

Comment: Thank you for your suggention, but i tried and it still doesn't work :/.

Answer (score 1):

Original Answer by [Mmerrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125332/mmerrell) at [Getting 404.0 error for ASP.NET MVC 3 app on IIS 7.0 / Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111091/getting-404-0-error-for-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-iis-7-0-windows-server-2008?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> You actually just reminded me that I needed to fix this issue in an
>   enviroment here. If your situation is the same as mine then it's a
>   simple fix.
>
> Just add the following to your web config:

```
 <system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```