# IIS 403 on deploy, no authentication should be needed

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-config

I have a simple web application written in C# MVC.  It does not require a login or any authentication whatsoever for the user.  I deployed it to my IIS Server.  I get a 403 Forbidden error in the browser.

I've tried tweaking the authentication in all sorts of ways (enabling/disabling various authentication in IIS).  I *thought* that Anonymous Authentication Enabled should be all I need.

I even tried adding something to my web.config saying allow *.  No joy.  Also tried setting authentication mode none.  No luck there either.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions as to IIS Training, I'd love to hear about it.  I've been able to get by thus far but it is a tool in my belt that is not as sharp as it should be.

Suggestions?  Thanks to you good people in advance.

UPDATE: Fix.

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in web config under system.webserver did the trick.

Comment: What version of IIS, .Net Framework, Windows Server? Depending on that, the cause of this error could be different. See the answers in this thread and maybe 1 of them will resolve your problem base on your environment. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980688/325521

Comment: .net 4.5, Windows Server 2008, IIS6  4.0 Application Pool.

Comment: Tried all that, too.  No luck.  Puzzling.

Comment: Odd.  Just noticed when deploying it moves the authentication in IIS to "Forms".  Why would this be?

Comment: Further update.  I notice that it's a 403.14.  Also, I get a 404 on all individual pages.  (e.g. if I go to domain/pagename I get a 404.

Comment: Could a problem with RouteConfig throw a 403 on the root and a 404 on all other pages?

Comment: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> was the issue.  Noted above.  Thanks for your help