# One of the controllers return 403 after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-403

I have just publish my ASP.Net MVC application online ..
but all the actions and controllers work fine for registered users.

only one of them return 403 .. ?

locally everything works perfectly.

Any debugging suggestion will be very helpful.. any ideas as well

I know its something with the routing engine .. 
as the direct url : `/UserPortal/Portal/Portal` works well
 = Area,  = Controller,  = Action

But when i use: `/UserPortal/`
It returns 403 ..

i have the following in my `UserPortalAreaRegistration.cs`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "UserPortal_default",
                "UserPortal",
                new { controller = "Portal", action = "Portal", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "UserPortal_standard",
                "UserPortal/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide an code sample?

Comment: A few possible solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043168/403-forbidden-after-publishing-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Yeah this i already know .. And applied .  thus is why the rest of the app is working .. Only the default rute to the user portal return 403.. Something is very wrong there :/

Answer (score 0):

It can be route template issue. Your first route's template is "UserPortal", but your url is "UserPortal/". So first route isn't matched. Try removing slash and see if it works. Also I suggest you to completely remove first route and add defaults to second one:

```
new { controller = "Portal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```